# How can I force git to request password for setting up Personal Access Token?

Tags: git, github

Since regular git passwords are being deprecated in favor of Personal Access Tokens (PATs), I'm trying to make the switch.  I've created my token in GitHub.

I'm on MacOS.

I do a `git clone <MYREPO>` expecting to be prompted for a username/password, but it doesn't.  It faithfully clones the repo, presumably with my old password.

How can I get git to re-prompt me for uid/pwd so I can enter my token?

Notes:

- I've tried

```
git credential-osxkeychain erase
host=www.github.com
protocol=https
```

Still didn't ask for my uid/pwd

- I'm the only account on this Mac.
- I don't see a .git directory either in current directory or user's home dir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to erase the password from your actual keychain. Please follow the instructions at

https://docs.github.com/en/github/using-git/updating-credentials-from-the-macos-keychain

and

https://docs.github.com/en/github/using-git/caching-your-github-credentials-in-git

Comment: Did that, and confirmed it was gone from the list.  Same--didn't prompt me when I did a git clone.

Comment: Well I’ve done this and I assure you that it works. I think you have not found the correct keychain entry. Or you are not using http clone (you might be using ssh clone). Or the repo is public!

Comment: Ah!  Yes!  The repo is public.  Docs didn't mention that, but I should have known.  When I did a push it prompted.

Comment: Lol and glad you got it sorted. And yes the docs did mention it.